# regex pattern to match single dot

Tags: regex

Is it possible to write a pattern such that it checks continuous occurrence of a character

should match

> "a.p@l.com","a.p.c@l.com"

and it should not  match

> "a..p@k.com".

Basically i need this to check if the email address is valid

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

If the language supports it, you can use [negative look-ahead and look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)
```

This will only match a period not following or preceding a period. See it in action [here](http://rubular.com/r/dnfBZqHKiD).

Answer (score 2):

You can invert you regex to match `>1` dots - if it doesn't, string is valid:

```
\.{2,}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are regex for email validation. No need to reinvent the wheel.

What would work with your examples should be `(\w\.?)+@(\w\.?)+`

Answer (score 0):

This will match one dot in a row in every string

```
\.[^.]
```

or you can check for all characters which should be there only one time in a row

```
[.-,]{1}
```

Comment: First one will always match the last dot and the second one will generate a match for each dot (both if evaluated alone).